# Unexplained S3 ListBuckets cost in cost explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

We are trying to optimise AWS S3. The cost explorer shows very high cost of ListBuckets calls.

To get the source of these calls, we enabled the CloudTrails with configuration to log all the management and data eventtype logs for S3. In the cloudtrail logs, there is not even 0.0001% of the calls which are reflected in the cost explorer. What can be the possible reasons for this?

Is the ListBuckets in cost explorer related to some other API in CloudTrail?
Or are the ListBuckets events not getting logged in CloudTrail becuase am I doing something wrong while configuring the CloudTrails?

Comment: Are you talking about the `s3:ListBucket` action?

Comment: The API call is [ListBuckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html), which needs the `s3:ListBucket` permission. According to [Amazon S3 CloudTrail events - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-logging-s3-info.html), this bucket-level action should be included in CloudTrail. Is the Trail configured to record actions in **all regions?**

Comment: @JohnRotenstein! Yes, the CloudTrail was configured to record actions in all regions. A few ListBuckets events also showed up in the CloudTrails logs, but the number is nowhere close to the one in the cost explorer.

Comment: @jellycsc! In the cost explorer, there is a filter called 'API operation'. In that filter, the operation name is 'ListBucket', which is responsible for high costs.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html):

> [ListBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) action
> Grants permission to list some or all of the objects in an Amazon S3 bucket (up to 1000)

I always find this naming confusing. The `ListBucket` operation lists the *contents* of buckets, not to be confused with `ListBuckets` permission that is associated with the `ListAllMyBuckets` action. Confusing indeed!

So, I think it is actually charging you for **listing the *contents* of buckets**. In boto3 this is called `list_objects()`. So, look for anything in Cost Explorer that might talk about **listing objects within a bucket** and it will probably show more data.